# PowerShell, more efficient way to find duplicate folders

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I wrote a little function to scan each folder in `$PSModulePath` to see if duplicate folder names exist in the various paths in there (as I've found this problem happening quite often in my PowerShell environments!). I use simple logic and I was wondering if some PowerShell gurus maybe have more compact / faster / more efficient ways to achieve a sweep like this (I quite often find that those better at PowerShell seem to have 2-line solutions to something that takes me 15 lines! :-) )?

I'm just taking a path in `$PSModulePath` and creating an array of the subfolder names there, then looking at the subfolders of the *other* paths in `$PSModulePath` and comparing them one by one against the array that I made for the first path, and then repeating for the other paths.

```
function Find-ModuleDuplicates {
    $hits = ""
    $ModPaths = $env:PSModulePath -Split ";" -replace "\\+$", "" | sort
    foreach ($i in $ModPaths) {
        foreach ($j in $ModPaths) {
            if ($j -notlike "*$i*") {
                $arr_i = (gci $i -Dir).Name
                $arr_j = (gci $j -Dir).Name
                foreach ($x in $arr_j) {
                    if ($arr_i -contains $x) {
                        $hits += "Module '$x' in '$i' has a duplicate`n" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($hits -ne "") { echo "" ; echo $hits }
    else { "`nNo duplicate Module folders were found`n" }
}
```

Comment: Populate a [`[HashTable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7) with the folder name as key.  Hash tables are based on a binary search and therefore very fast.

Comment: For such a small search the speed increase would be negligible though, right? I completely agree that if I was searching thousands of folders, your point would be really important for sure (if I was to extend to a general DeDup script for example). With a hashtable would you be able to achieve the result in much fewer lines also do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a solution using Group-Object.

```
$env:PSModulePath.Split(";") | gci -Directory | group Name |
where Count -gt 1 | select Count,Name,@{ n = "ModulePath"; e = { $_.Group.Parent.FullName } }
```

Comment: Nicely done; to make the command cross-platform, use `$env:PSModulePath -split [IO.Path]::PathSeparator`

Comment: It''s amazing thanks; a complete dedup tool in one line. So many uses. I just adapted it to look for duplicate video files on two drives that I keep media files on: `"g:\TV\*", "h:\TV\*" | gci -i *.avi,*.mkv -Recurse | group Name | where Count -gt 1 | select Count,Name,@{ n = "Paths"; e = { $_.Group.Parent.FullName } }` but I'm doing something wrong with the Paths output, as that field is always returning empty, maybe the inclusion of `-Recurse` is making that property fail to populate?

Comment: For files, specify the `Directory` property instead of `Parent`. `$_.Group.Directory`